# SQL Query to count the number of each element in an object

Tags: sql, database, count

I have a database table like this:

```
Room Name     ||     Animal
----------------------------
Room1 || Cat
Room1 || Dog
Room1 || Dog
Room2 || Cat
Room2 || Cat
Room2 || Dog
Room2 || Dog
```

I want to read this table with a SQL query and as result I want to count the number of each animal in the room:

```
Room1: 1 cat 2 dog
Room2: 2 cats 2 dog
```

(The output format doesn't matter)

Is there a SQL query that can help? Or should I read the whole table and filter it programatically?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [Room Name], [Animal], COUNT(*) FROM TableName GROUP BY [Room Name], [Animal]
```

This would return

```
Room 1 | Cat | 1
Room 1 | Dog | 2
Room 2 | Cat | 2
Room 2 | Dog | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select room_name, animal, count(*)
from table 
group by room_name, animal
```